# Register backend module in TYPO3 8.x upgraded from TYPO3 4.x

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-extensions, typo3-8.x, typo3-4.5

I have my extension in TYPO3 4.x with Backened module (EXT:wec_map),

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addModule(
    'tools','txwecmapM1',
    '',
    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::extPath('wec_map').'Classes/Module/MapAdministration/'
);
```

Now, I upgraded TYPO3 4.x to TYPO3 8.7.8. I'm having an issue with backend module its shows empty space in the tools menu group. I have replaced deprecated module registration method like this:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerModule(
    'txwecmapM1',
    'tools', // Make module a submodule of 'web'
    'txwecmapM1', // Submodule key
    '', // Position
    [
        'access' => 'user,group',
        'icon'   => 'EXT:' . $extKey . '/Resources/Public/Icons/user_mod_bewebuser.svg',
        'labels' => 'LLL:EXT:' . $extKey . '/Resources/Private/Languages/Module/MapAdministration/locallang_mod.xlf',
    ]
);
```

It's working nice but the icon shows default typo3 icon and label shows ":mlang_labels_tablabel". can anyone help me out in this?

second thing, while i click on module its shows:

```
"Could not analyse class: "Tx_TxwecmapM1_Controller_accessController" maybe not loaded or no autoloader? Class Tx_TxwecmapM1_Controller_accessController does not exist"
```

Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

The module definition looks perfectly ok to me - 
but AFAIK, it should read `$_EXTKEY` instead of `$extKey`.

Oh, and the second problem might be caused by not using the namespace here.

This should do it:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerModule(
    'Vendor.' . $_EXTKEY,
    'tools', // Make module a submodule of 'web'
    'txwecmapM1', // Submodule key
    '', // Position
    [
        'access' => 'user,group',
        'icon'   => 'EXT:' . $_EXTKEY . '/Resources/Public/Icons/user_mod_bewebuser.svg',
        'labels' => 'LLL:EXT:' . $_EXTKEY . '/Resources/Private/Languages/Module/MapAdministration/locallang_mod.xlf',
    ]
);
```

Comment: Best thing to test this is uninstall extension, clear system caches, install extension again. Did that help?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party but still here is the way to do it (thx to typo3 slack).

Create a Controller in Classes/Controller which extends `\TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Module\BaseScriptClass` and add the following functions:

```
function loadMCONF()
{
    $this->MCONF = $GLOBALS['TBE_MODULES']['_configuration']['myext_mymoduleM1'];
}

function init()
{
    $this->loadMCONF();
    parent::init();

    $this->getBackendUser()->modAccess($this->MCONF, 1);
    $this->pageRenderer = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Page\PageRenderer::class);
    $this->doc = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Template\DocumentTemplate::class);
}


public function mainAction(\Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface $request, \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface $response)
{
    $this->postVars = $request->getParsedBody();
    $this->init();
    $this->main();
    $response->getBody()->write($this->content . $this->doc->endPage());
    return $response;
}`
```

that way you can recycle most of your old code from main() and init().

Use addModule to register the module:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addModule(
    'myext',
    'mymoduleM1',
    '',
    '',
    [
        'routeTarget' => \MyVendor\MyExt\Controller\BackendModuleController::class . '::mainAction',
        'access' => 'admin',
        'name' => 'myext_mymoduleM1',
        'labels' => [
            'tabs_images' => [
                'tab' => 'EXT:myext/Resources/Public/Icons/BackendModule.svg',
            ],
            'll_ref' => 'LLL:EXT:myext/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_mod.xml',
        ]
    ]
);
```